# binary operation between rows in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Original Dataframe as below,

```
s1 = pd.DataFrame([1,'a',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,2,'b',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,3,'c',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]).T
In [37]: s1
Out[37]: 
1  a  NaN  NaN  NaN  2  b  NaN  NaN  NaN  3  c  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Desired DataFrame

```
Nan  1  NaN  NaN  NaN  Nan  2  NaN  NaN  NaN  Nan  3  NaN  NaN  NaN
Nan  a  NaN  NaN  NaN  Nan  b  NaN  NaN  NaN  Nan  c  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

My solution:

```
s2 =s1.shift(periods=1,axis=1)
s=pd.concat([s2,s1],axis='index',join='inner',ignore_index=True,copy=False)
print(s)
Nan 1  a  NaN  NaN  NaN  2  b  NaN  NaN  NaN  3  c  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  a  NaN  NaN  NaN  2  b  NaN  NaN  NaN  3  c  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Then, how can I give each column value of NaN except that 2 rows in that column are all non-NaN? I wasted 2 hours on this small issue trying to come up a pythonic way to do it except if/else/for loop. 
last step will be,

`s.fillna(method='ffill',axis=1,inplace=True)`

Thanks in advance

Comment: so basically the data `[1, 'a', NaN, NaN, NaN, Nan]` means that the `NaN` goes for both `1` and `a`? That's why you want this same data displayed twice, one time with the 1 in the first row and one time with the `a` in the 2nd row?

Comment: sorry, I do not understand what you mean. but there are no connection between number of 'NaN' and 1 or 'a'. I just want to move digits (1, or 2, or 3) up 1 layer to be on top of 'a', 'b' and 'c' respectively.

Comment: ok, understood. And why does the desired output have a NaN as first column plus an additional NaN after 1 and 2 but not after 3? Is that intentional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create mask for columns with [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) `NaN`s values and then set `NaN`s by `loc`:

```
s2 = s1.shift(periods=1,axis=1)
#added ignore_index=True for default unique index
s = pd.concat([s2,s1], axis='index', ignore_index=True)

m = s.isnull().any()
#alternative
#m = ~s.notnull().all()
s.loc[:, m] = np.nan
print(s)
    0  1    2    3    4    5  6    7    8    9    10 11   12   13   14
0  NaN  1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  3  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  a  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  b  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  c  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Detail:

```
print(s.isnull())
     0      1     2     3     4     5      6     7     8     9     10     11  \
0  True  False  True  True  True  True  False  True  True  True  True  False   
1  True  False  True  True  True  True  False  True  True  True  True  False   

     12    13    14  
0  True  True  True  
1  True  True  True  

print(m)
0      True
1     False
2      True
3      True
4      True
5      True
6     False
7      True
8      True
9      True
10     True
11    False
12     True
13     True
14     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: what does `s.loc[:, m] = np.nan` do?

Comment: It set NaNs by boolean mask.

Comment: yes, I got that, but the `, m` thingie, is that documented somewhere?

Comment: It means apply mask per columns, not default by rows. I am looking for it in docs, but I cannot find it.

Comment: @hansaplast not sure if this is what you are looking for, https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#boolean-reductions.